# Where is setVisible in Netbeans palette?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans on design mode for to make a gui. I am looking for a property corresponding to the `setVisible` method of java and I can not find it.

I have looked in Properties and Binding, but have found nothing.

At last I have written `this.component.setVisible(false);` in Post-Init Code in the section of the pallet code.

Is there another way to do this?

PS: I use Netbeans 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope!

If you're using netbeans the default is to open components as visible. As far as i'm aware this can't be changed unless you do not use a GUI builder such as netbeans.

As you said in your question you can just simply set the component's .setVisible() parameter to false or true depending on what you would like!

Answer (score 17):

What I did was right click the label and go to Customize code and make the label visibility as false.